# passing an array as output from one job and printing the input array list in other job using githubactions

Tags: powershell, github, yaml, github-actions, github-for-windows

I am looking for a way to pass array as Output for one job and use it as Input for another job and print it in github actions.

```
 parse-json:
 needs: start
 runs-on: [self-hosted,X64,dev,Windows]
 outputs: 
  inputvar: ${{steps.parsejson.outputs.argumentlist}}
 steps:
   - name: Parse JSON and read the input variable definitions 
     id: parsejson
     run: |
      $path= "${{github.workspace}}\.github\workflows\parameter.json" 
      $path -replace ' ', '` '
      $json = Get-Content  $path | ConvertFrom-Json
      $arglist = @{}
      $json.PSObject.properties | ForEach-Object -Process {$name=$_.Name; $arglist[$name] = $_.Value }
      echo '::set-output name=argumentlist::$arglist'
    
test:
 needs: parse-json
 runs-on: [self-hosted,X64,dev,Windows]
 steps:
  - run: echo ${{needs.parse-json.outputs.inputvar[prebuild]}}
```

I get   (Line: 58, Col: 13): Unrecognized named-value: 'prebuild'. Located at position 35 within expression: needs.parse-json.outputs.inputvar[prebuild]

Comment: According to the GitHub Actions docs, "*job outputs are strings*" so you'll probably need to serialize your ```$arglist``` (e.g. with ```ConvertTo-Json```) before you do ```echo '::set-output...``` and then deserialize it again when you want to consume it. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs. Note also your  ```$path -replace ' ', '` '``` expression doesn't mutate the value of ```$path``` - it just returns a new value which you're not capturing, so ```$path``` still contains its original value.